# Using Selenium with windows authentication

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I would like to use selenium to test a multi-user scenario where

1. User A logs in (via windows auth), 
   performs a certain action
2. User B logs in (via windows auth), see's that user A has performed a certain action.

for this to work I would need to identify with different credentials.

My target is Chrome

`Alert().SetAuthenticationCredentials` does not seem to work